# order of parameters in differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

I am completely mystified about parameters in differential forms and wherever I looked it's just glossed over.

Take for example the $2-$form $\omega = dx\land dy$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Usually it's just defined like that, but given two vectors $(x,v_1), (x,v_2)$ in the tangent space at $x$, it shold be that $dx \land dy = dy \land dx$, since
$$(dx \land dy) (x)((x,v_1), (x,v_2)) = $$
$$- (dy \land dx)(x)((x,v_2)(x,v_1))=$$
$$ (dy \land dx)(x)((x,v_1)(x,v_2))=$$

According to my book, tough, $dx \land dy = - dy \land dx$.
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're writing incorrect equations. Once you evaluate individual terms, there are no more wedges. The correct equation, using your (cumbersome!) notation, is
\begin{multline*}
(dx\wedge dy)((x,v_1),(x,v_2)) = dx((x,v_1))dy((x,v_2)) - dx((x,v_2))dy((x,v_1)).
\end{multline*}
And of course from this you see that, in fact, $dx\wedge dy = -dy\wedge dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

It's a misunderstanding of the anticommutativity of the wedge product of alternating tensors. I previously thought for some reason that, given $f,g$ alternating k-tensor and m-tensor respectively on $V$, with $V$ vector space over $\mathbb{R}$,
$$(f \land g) (x_1, ..., x_k, ..., x_{k+m}) = (-1)^{km} (g \land f) (x_{k+1}, ..., x_{k+m}, x_1, ..., x_k)$$
while of course it is:
$$(f \land g) (x_1, ..., x_k, ..., x_{k+m}) = (-1)^{km} (g \land f) (x_1, ..., x_k, ..., x_{k+m})$$
so the error is in the first equality.

Comment: I'm puzzled why you didn't respond to my answer 5 days ago. No, your lines are still nonsense (as I said, once you evaluate on vectors you do not have a wedge product, and your definition of the wedge product is just wrong). Regardless, your claim here is incorrect for general $k$ and $m$. It holds only when both $k$ and $m$ are odd. Maybe you should understand why that is.

Comment: Now the lines should be correct. I wasn't trying to evaluate the tensor, just applying anticommutativity of the wedge product

Comment: Maybe I'm doing some other mistakes now, but that's the one I've found. Please tell me if I'm still wrong or if I'm making another mistake altogether

Comment: You *are* evaluating when you write $dx((x,v_1))$; that is a scalar, so it makes no sense to write things like $dx((x,v_1))\wedge dy((x,v_2))$.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I'm gonna correct it to show what I actually meant